# Angularfire: Display key instead of value in HTML for a Firebase Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am using AngularFire for a project. My firebase Object is of the form

```
{
   mainKey: {
      key1:value1,
      key2:value2
   },
   mainkey2: {
      key3:value3
   }
}
```

I have entered the data in such a way that I need to display both the `value` and the `key` in different columns of a table row.

I am able to display `value` using `{{key}}` expression but what should I do if I have to display the `key` itself?

Is storing data in this way a wrong practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the way to do so in **angularJS** docs

```
    <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in object"> {{key}}> </li>
    </ul>
```

This would give me all the keys listed.

Answer (score 0):

[**You can use the `$id` property.**](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html#section-meta-fields)

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="message in messages">
    Message data located at node /messages/{{ message.$id }}
    Message text is {{ message.text }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried using it but nothing is displayed when I use {{key.$id}}

Comment: `<tbody ng-repeat="product in sellerBids.sellerProductBids"> 
     <tr ng-repeat="bid in product.userbids">
      <td>{{product.name.$id}} </td>
      <td>{{product.price |currency:"&#8377;"}} </td>
      <td>{{bid.$id}} </td>
      <td>{{bid |currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>`

Comment: Not in the comments, but in the question.

Comment: In your case though you access `$id` on the object like `product.$id`. Since product is that you're looping through.

Comment: but I'm also looping through product.userbids

Comment: Can you create an example in Plnkr? That will help me debug it for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98929/discussion-between-satwik-and-david-east).